# Multicolored CSS content in a .tooltip element

Tags: html, css

I'm using the css `.tooltip` function to display some information about a link on my web app. When the mouse hovers over it, I'd like for the content text within the tooltip element to be multi-colored; i.e. the first word will be a different color from the remaining words. I've found articles about changing the color via html, but that's not helpful for me given that I'm using the css `.tooltip`.

CSS code here:

```
.tooltip:hover:after{
    background: #BABABA;
    border-radius: 0px;
    top: 15px;
    font: 12px MyWebFont250, serif;
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 200%;
    content: "Word is Pudaes nonsequi dolo magni acipsam sam, con et et que et ilit accabo. Nam qui officit ent qui coribus dolorem quissite exeraecae porupta eptaqui nia pliquibus, cum quia esedit. \A \A Proris ulluptaes et lautecti ad u lltem acestibusdae cuptati untur, eume et anim dolut iunt, cumqui ullut arum aut doluptatem.";
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text-align: left;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 250px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #AAAAAA;
}
```

Also, I know that CSS should be used for formatting and HTML for content, but I'm not sure how to incorporate content into the `.tooltip` element unless I use something like `content: attr(title);` in place of the above content line, and then put all of the above content ("Word is Pudaes nonsequi...") into the `title` attribute in html. This still doesn't help to solve my multi-colored text requirement.

Comment: Nice start for your post

Comment: check out http://w3lessons.info/2014/02/13/fancy-tooltips-using-css3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a tooltip in the HTML, hide it and then display it when the tooltip text is highlighted. You can then use appropriate HTML markup to provide emphasis with colours. In this case with `<strong>`.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/U6eef/1/)

HTML

```
<p> 
    <a>hover me</a> 
    <span class="tooltip"><strong>This</strong> is my tooltip</span> 
</p>
```

CSS

```
 .tooltip {
    background: #BABABA;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font: 12px MyWebFont250, serif;
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 200%;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 250px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #AAAAAA;
    display: none;
}
.tooltip strong {
    color: #F00;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover + .tooltip {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi @user3822153 - if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.